# ENOENT: no such file or directory

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

I made a small project with authentication based on this example https://github.com/lyndachiwetelu/using-passport-with-sequelize-and-mysql. I had a mistake "Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\user\Desktop\using-passport-with-sequelize-and-mysql-master\app\views\layouts\main.hbs'"
But I did not point this way anywhere, it's strange. I beg you to help me, guys <3

I've alrready tried to make such way, and create such file(main.hbs), but in this case i can't reach another pathes ( dashboard, signin ). In this case they all have the same html-code from main.hbs

server.js :

```
var express    = require('express')
var app        = express()
var passport   = require('passport')
var session    = require('express-session')
var bodyParser = require('body-parser')
var env        = require('dotenv').config()
var exphbs     = require('express-handlebars')



//For BodyParser
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());


 // For Passport
app.use(session({ secret: 'keyboard cat',resave: true, 
saveUninitialized:true})); // session secret
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session()); // persistent login sessions


 //For Handlebars
app.set('views', './app/views')
app.engine('hbs', exphbs({extname: '.hbs'}));
app.set('view engine', '.hbs');


app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.send('Welcome to Passport with Sequelize');
});


//Models
var models = require("./app/models");


//Routes
var authRoute = require('./app/routes/auth.js')(app,passport);


//load passport strategies
require('./app/config/passport/passport.js')(passport,models.user);


//Sync Database
models.sequelize.sync().then(function(){
console.log('Nice! Database looks fine')

}).catch(function(err){
console.log(err,"Something went wrong with the Database Update!")
});



app.listen(5000, function(err){
    if(!err)
    console.log("Site is live"); else console.log(err)

});
```

app/routes/auth.js :

```
var authController = require('../controllers/authcontroller.js');

module.exports = function(app,passport){

app.get('/signup', authController.signup);


app.get('/signin', authController.signin);


app.post('/signup', passport.authenticate('local-signup',  { successRedirect: '/dashboard',
failureRedirect: '/signup'}
                                                ));


 app.get('/dashboard',isLoggedIn, authController.dashboard);


 app.get('/logout',authController.logout);


 app.post('/signin', passport.authenticate('local-signin',  { successRedirect: '/dashboard',
 failureRedirect: '/signin'}
                                                ));


 function isLoggedIn(req, res, next) {
if (req.isAuthenticated())
    return next();

 res.redirect('/signin');
```

}

}

app/contrroller/authcontroller.js :

```
 var exports = module.exports = {}


 exports.signup = function(req,res){

 res.render('signup');
```

}

```
 exports.signin = function(req,res){

 res.render('signin');
```

}

```
 exports.dashboard = function(req,res){

 res.render('dashboard');
```

}

```
  exports.logout = function(req,res){

  req.session.destroy(function(err) {
  res.redirect('/');
```

});

}

In folder "app\views" only files with html-code, so i don't show them.

I still can't understand where program take this path \app\views\layouts\main.hbs

PROBLEM: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\user\Desktop\using-passport-with-sequelize-and-mysql-master\app\views\layouts\main.hbs'

[error_screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rpYyN.png)

[structure_screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iBFid.png)

Comment: can you maybe screenshot the whole error message?

Comment: that is whole error message. I mean that program work( server is live ), but when i come to http://localhost:5000/signup i got this Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\user\Desktop\using-passport-with-sequelize-and-mysql-master\app\views\layouts\main.hbs'

Comment: right but if you screen shot the error it will give clues as to where that error is happening

Comment: I already add screen, the same i got in Atom

Comment: Seems to be [how it works](https://github.com/ericf/express-handlebars#basic-usage).

Comment: Oh, i showed it in github model in start of my massege< but k, i will add screnshot of this one too, 1 sec, pls)

Comment: Screenshot done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Express-Handlerbars (the view engine you're using) expects a `main` layout file which you can see on the docs (search for "main.handlebars") https://github.com/ericf/express-handlebars

You can also see the directory structure express handlebars expects under https://github.com/ericf/express-handlebars#basic-usage

This acts as a "main" layout that your other views extend. So you can put common code in `main` such as a navbar etc.

You can either follow the docs or when you render your views use `{layout:false}` as one of the props passed in e.g

```
res.render('home', {layout: false});
```

and see if that works. You can also read about the `defaultLayout` here https://github.com/ericf/express-handlebars#defaultlayout

You could potentially try setting the default layout to false by default, though I don't know what effect this will have or if there are other unintended consequences. It might not even work at all.

```
app.engine('hbs', exphbs({extname: '.hbs', defaultLayout:false}));
```

Your best bet is to use a main layout, so you can put the common code in there, so if you wanted to update your logo for example you would only have to do it in 1 place rather than every view.

To do this, in your "views" directory create another directory called "layouts" and add a file called "main.hbs" with the following code in it. The `{{{body}}}` area is where your code from other views will be rendered.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Example App</title>
</head>
<body>

    {{{body}}}

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Then how can I write directory ( dashboard, sigup)? Cz as i understand it isn't see them in my program now.

Comment: And also, as i understand i need to put this 
res.render('home', {layout: false});
to use my directory ?

Comment: Either create the main file as outlined in the docs I linked, or use the `res.render` method with the `defaultLayout` set to false as I mentioned. To be honest you will want a `main` layout so you're not copy/pasting the same html code to every page which would also make updating a nightmare

Comment: You would use something like  `res.render('signup', {defaultLayout:false});` for your examples

Comment: But how i will show path to dashboard, cz as i said in my problem up here, if i use main directory as it want, every page( dashboard, signin) got the same html-code from main.hbs

Comment: I'm assuming your `main` file was missing the correct `{{{body}}}` template tag. I don't know what your javascript experience is, but I would suggest you read up on variables and template engines

Comment: I'm new in it (( And res.render('signup', {defaultLayout:false}); don't help me (((

Comment: Create the `main.hbs` file as I suggest in my post, with the content I have in my post. The important part is that the `main.hbs` file has the `{{{body}}}` code. When you then do something such as `res.render('dashboard')` it will render the `main.hbs` file, but when it encounters the `{{{body}}}` code, it will load the `dashboard.hbs` file and insert the contents of that file into the `{{{body}}}` variable. Please try that, your over code doesn't need to change, provided your main layout is correct as I've put above

Comment: {{{body}}} in the main.hbs file, exactly as I have above in the main answer

Comment: Error: Parse error on line 9:
   ...<body>
   {{{res.render('signup', {de
   -------------------^
   Expecting 'ID', got 'INVALID'

Comment: No don't put the `{{{res.render...` line in your main.hbs, put  `{{{body}}}` exactly as i wrote. Use the word body. The template engine will replace it for you.

Comment: Omg, i'm so nooby< i need to study and study and study moreeeee. Thank you very much <3<3<3 Sorry, if i spend your time(

Comment: Glad you got it working. We all have to start somewhere, so just keep practicing and playing around. But I'd suggest really trying to understand the various parts you are using rather than just blindly writing the code to further your understanding. And by all means ask questions on sites like this if you really get stuck

Comment: By the way, one more question pls, where i can findd css of, for example, button which i had there in signup ? Is it in node_modules ? Or where i can change it ?

Comment: Most like in the public folder in styles.css

Comment: I mean, where is this style.css, cz i see and know that that button got styles, but it was created auto, so if i want to change it, where i can find style.css file ?

Comment: or i need to write it by myself and it will change button 100% ?